# How do I make HTTP POST requests with grequests

Tags: python, grequests

I tried the following:

```
import grequests

urls = ['http://localhost/test', 'http://localhost/test']

params = {'a':'b', 'c':'d'}
rs = (grequests.post(u, params) for u in urls)
grequests.map(rs)
```

But it says the following:

```
File "search.py", line 6, in <genexpr>
rs = (grequests.post(u, params) for u in urls)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

I also need to pass the response to a callback for processing.

Comment: Can you give the exact line number of the error message? I don't see anywhere in your code that you're calling something with 4 arguments.

Comment: It is in line number 6. I have updated the question with the error message.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

grequests.post() function takes only one positional argument i.e URL to which you have send that POST request. The rest of the parameters are taken as key word arguments.

So you need to call grequests.post() as:

```
import grequests

urls = ['http://localhost/test', 'http://localhost/test']

params = {'a':'b', 'c':'d'}
rs = (grequests.post(u, data=params) for u in urls)
grequests.map(rs)
```

Comment: I tried that and it's appending the parameters to the URL instead of sending it in the content body.

Comment: You need to use 'data' instead of 'param' for a POST request. data=params